# How to implement the api which is working file in postman but not in the real code

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios

I am working on chrome extension. The purpose of the extension is to take the screenshots and upload them somewhere. I am having problem to upload the screenshots. The data which needs to be posted is given by backend developer.

```
curl --location --request POST 'bug-stage.helloyomo.com:8381/upload-screenshots' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'id: <id-token-generated-after-login>' \
--form 'my_file=@"<file-path>"' \
--form 'my_file=@"<file-path>"' \
--form 'projectid="<project-id>"'
```

According to postman the following code should be used in node.js. Follow is the way. `maheer.jpg` is the file inside the main directory. In node js the api returns correct response.

```
var axios = require("axios");
var FormData = require("form-data");
var fs = require("fs");
var data = new FormData();
data.append("my_file", fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/maheer.jpg"));
data.append("projectid", "c5a28abf-139c-4bc7-90e3-a75b350e6670");

var config = {
   method: "post",
   url: "http://bug-stage.helloyomo.com:8381/upload-screenshots",
   headers: {
      id: "<id>",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      ...data.getHeaders(),
   },
   data: data,
};

axios(config)
   .then(function (response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
   });
```

Now I need to make it work on the client side. But the problem is that I don't have any image stored locally on my system there. I have a canvas which I converted to the `File` object. But I am not sure what should I pass in place of image path.

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("id", "<id>");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("my_file", fileInput.files[0], "/C:/Users/HB Laptop point/Desktop/DM/2.jpg");
formdata.append("projectid", "c5a28abf-139c-4bc7-90e3-a75b350e6670");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: formdata,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("bug-stage.helloyomo.com:8381/upload-screenshots", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

**Note:** In above code `fileInput` is html input element. I add some image to test.

When I use this code it returns EMPTY_RESPONSE_ERR. If you guys have any further question please ask in comments. I will be here.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please correct me if i understand this incorrectly.

One of the things i have noticed is you are making a post call to an api with data which actually is a readStream of a image file. And then you're setting the headers as `x-www-form-urlencoded` which actually sends data in as json file format i think? (again please correct me if im wrong).
I'm failing to understand how you can send a  stream of data through axios. I think to do something like this you need to pipe the stream and also specify "content-length" on the headers or else it will return a empty response. There was a feature request on axios lib you can check this: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/961

Also can you shed more light on the path you are uploading the file is a storage system? an cloud instance or a file storage system like s3? or firestorage?

So if the image is actually getting uploaded to a storage system, you can simply get the bucket name and ask the backend developer to share the accesskey and token(in case of aws s3) and you can pass that path directly wherever you want to render the image. ex: suppose your screenshot is uploaded on a aws s3 storage class standard it will have a path like: `https:"//bucket-name-here.s3.region-here-1.amazonaws.com/{IMAGE_PATH_ON_S3}`.

Currently i think the url you are posting data stream to is maybe a cdn? i do not know for sure.